# Compressing the image on upload without affecting dimension of image

Tags: laravel

I need to compress the image on upload keeping the original dimensions of image. I have used Intervention package of Laravel and am successful in compressing the image size, but, the resize() function also changes dimensions. Is it possible to just reduce the size of image without changing the dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [documentation of Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize), you can resize while maintaining the aspect ratio:

```
// resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
$img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
  $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the files using the HTML5 FileReader API with .readAsArrayBuffer

Create e Blob with the file data and get its url with

window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

Create new Image element and set it's src to the file blob url

Send the image to the canvas. The canvas size is set to desired output size

Get the scaled-down data back from canvas via canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7) (set your own output format and quality)

Attach new hidden inputs to the original form and transfer the dataURI images basically as normal text

On backend, read the dataURI, decode from Base64, and save it

var fileinput = document.getElementById('fileinput');

```
var max_width = fileinput.getAttribute('data-maxwidth');
var max_height = fileinput.getAttribute('data-maxheight');

var preview = document.getElementById('preview');

var form = document.getElementById('form');

function processfile(file) {

    if( !( /image/i ).test( file.type ) )
        {
            alert( "File "+ file.name +" is not an image." );
            return false;
        }

    // read the files
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
      // blob stuff
      var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]); // create blob...
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); // and get it's URL

      // helper Image object
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = blobURL;
      //preview.appendChild(image); // preview commented out, I am using the canvas instead
      image.onload = function() {
        // have to wait till it's loaded
        var resized = resizeMe(image); // send it to canvas
        var newinput = document.createElement("input");
        newinput.type = 'hidden';
        newinput.name = 'images[]';
        newinput.value = resized; // put result from canvas into new hidden input
        form.appendChild(newinput);
      }
    };
}

function readfiles(files) {

    // remove the existing canvases and hidden inputs if user re-selects new pics
    var existinginputs = document.getElementsByName('images[]');
    var existingcanvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
    while (existinginputs.length > 0) { // it's a live list so removing the first element each time
      // DOMNode.prototype.remove = function() {this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}
      form.removeChild(existinginputs[0]);
      preview.removeChild(existingcanvases[0]);
    } 

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      processfile(files[i]); // process each file at once
    }
    fileinput.value = ""; //remove the original files from fileinput
    // TODO remove the previous hidden inputs if user selects other files
}

// this is where it starts. event triggered when user selects files
fileinput.onchange = function(){
  if ( !( window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob ) ) {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    return false;
    }
  readfiles(fileinput.files);
}

// === RESIZE ====

function resizeMe(img) {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  var width = img.width;
  var height = img.height;

  // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
  if (width > height) {
    if (width > max_width) {
      //height *= max_width / width;
      height = Math.round(height *= max_width / width);
      width = max_width;
    }
  } else {
    if (height > max_height) {
      //width *= max_height / height;
      width = Math.round(width *= max_height / height);
      height = max_height;
    }
  }

  // resize the canvas and draw the image data into it
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

  preview.appendChild(canvas); // do the actual resized preview

  return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7); // get the data from canvas as 70% JPG (can be also PNG, etc.)

}
```